# How the Spring maps url from a jsp to its respective controller?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring web project , I have many JSP files and many controllers , but I am not able to grab how this

```
<form:form action="updateCustomer" autocomplete="true"  commandName="customer">
```

form is automatically mapped to the respective controller in which the **updateCustomer** is defined. There are other controllers also but how exactly the url **updateCustomer** goes to respective controller.

The Customer.jsp file is as follows :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<link
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/bootstrap-nav-wizard.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/intlTelInput.css"
    rel="stylesheet">

<style>
ul.nav-wizard li a i {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
</style>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script     src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script     src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script     src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script     src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/custom/customer.js"></script>
<script     src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/jqueryform-validator.js"></script>
<script     src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/custom/common.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form:form action="updateCustomer" autocomplete="true"  commandName="customer">
        <form:hidden path="buyerId"/>
        <form:hidden path="user.userId" />
        <section>

            <div class="container" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3 class="main-title">My Profile</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div>

                        <!-- Main Content Start -->
                        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                            <!-- Step 1 Content Start -->
                            <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="step1">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title">Personal Details</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-group">
                                                <label>First Name</label><span class="req">*</span>
                                                <form:input class="form-control" path="user.firstName"
                                                      type="text"  maxlength="75"
                                                    />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-group">
                                                <label>Middle Name</label>
                                                <form:input class="form-control" path="user.middleName"   maxlength="75"
                                                    type="text" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 form-group">
                                                <label>Last Name</label><span class="req">*</span>
                                                <form:input class="form-control" path="user.lastName"
                                                      type="text"   maxlength="75"
                                                     />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                    </div><!--//panel body over -->
                                </div><!--//panel panel default over -->

                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h3 class="panel-title">Company Details</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 form-group">
                                                <label>Company Name</label><span class="req">*</span>
                                                <form:input path="companyName" class="form-control"
                                                      type="text"  
                                                    maxlength="45"
                                                     />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row" style="display: none;" id="mainBtn">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 pull-right" style="min-width: 170px;">
                                        <button class="btn" type="submit" name="action" value="2" style= "min-width: 170px;">Save & Continue</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 pull-right" style="text-align: right; padding-right:0px;">   <!--  added property  padding-right:0px; to style   on 17/7 -->
                                        <button class="btn" type="submit" name="action" value="1" style= "min-width: 170px;">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row"  id="editBtn">
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 pull-right">
                                        <a class="btn pull-right" id="edit"
                                            href="#" onclick="makeEditable()" style="min-width: 170px;">Edit</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br> <br>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Step 1 Content End -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- Main Content End -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /container -->
        </section>
    </form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

The controller File is as follows :

```
    package com.htss.web.controller;

//assume all imports

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/buyer")
public class BuyerController {


    @Autowired
    private BuyerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private CommonService commonService;
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/open/customer")
    public String customerInfo() {
        return "customer";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit_profile")
    public String editCustomerProfile(HttpSession session, Model model) {
        Integer buyerId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("entityId");
        BuyerFormBean bean = customerService.retrieveCustomer(buyerId);
        Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute("userId");
        try {
            UserFormBean user = userService.getUser(userId);
            bean.setUser(user);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        }
        model.addAttribute("customer", bean);
        model.addAttribute("countries", commonService.getCountryDropdown());
        model.addAttribute("action", "updateCustomer");
        return "buyerProfile";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateCustomer")
    public String updateCustomerProfile(Model model, HttpSession session, BuyerFormBean customer) {

        try {
            if (action == 1 || action == 2) {
                customer = customerService.modifyCustomer(customer);

            }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            model.addAttribute("error",messageSource.getMessage("msg.Error",null,Locale.US));
        }
        Integer buyerId = (Integer) session.getAttribute("entityId");
        BuyerFormBean bean = customerService.retrieveCustomer(buyerId);
        Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute("userId");        
        try {
            UserFormBean user = userService.getUser(userId);
            bean.setUser(user);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        }

        model.addAttribute("customer", bean);
        model.addAttribute("message",messageSource.getMessage("msg.Success",null,Locale.US));
        return "Customer";
    }


}
```

Now the question is when I click save button the url formed is :
http://localhost:8080/82ism/buyer/updateCustomer

How this happened ? and now when I need a button to some other controller I need to give the whole URL as follows :

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/seller/edit_profile
```

The project is working all fine I am just trying to understand this concept.

Comment: you can use `<c:url value="/updateCustomer" />` or `<spring:url value="/something" var="url" htmlEscape="true"/>` in links instead and they are `jsp, Spring` tags. Please read more about them to make yourself comfortable

Comment: The project is working fine already , i am looking for the concept not an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of spring is so you don't have to worry about that stuff.
jsp's get found cause of the propperty's in application.propperties:
like:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

For the forms and methods... It's not like it magicly happens.
A form you have to cal by name and methods are eighter mapped to a url or action

like:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
or
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

To call the values of a form from the controller you first have to bind them to a entity model with the fields of the form as variables.
The method would look like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)    
public String processRegister(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user,   
Map<String, Object> model) {
    ...
    return "view";
}
```

Comment: As i have shown the controller file as well , the only request mapping is of /buyer  , but we have not mentioned that in the action attribute of form , so how it is redirected to the BuyerController on its own.

Comment: You don't show the javascriptfiles that are beïng loaded, one is called formvalidator, so I gues your form is beïng handeld by javascript. Nothing in your controllerclass is handeling it. I wil post a new answer to show how a controller calls a form...

Comment: My bad. It's mapped to your controller. Your formaction is updateCustomer so that's the url that's been formed when you click the submit button. Your second method is mapped to that. So that's the one that's being called

Comment: yep, if you use the same controller

Comment: What I mean is the root path is  : http://localhost:8080/82ism/      and the rest comes from the action attribute i.e. updateCustomer  , so the url formed is http://localhost:8080/82ism/buyer/updateCustomer    , that means if I had define a request mapping  /updateCustomer is some other Controller (say Controller2)  then will the spring find that controller automatically too ?

Comment: The controller you put the method in dosn't mather, it's the action the form is mapped to that's being called. If you put your method in the home controller ("/"), the resulturl wil be  localhost:8080/82ism/updateCustomer